# Given BX. Get it Mirrored and put in CX. How to do this?

Tags: assembly

Given BX. Get it Mirrored. *You can only use SHR, SHL, AND, OR, XOR*.

For example:BX = 1234h CX = 4321h

Comment: Please read [ask]. Tell us what you've tried, and where you failed; don't just dump a homework assignment on us.

Comment: what do you mean by mirrored?  BX=1234h would flip to CX=2C48h right?  bitwise, nibblewise like you have shown and bytewise BX = 1234h CX = 3412h

Comment: CX = 4321h. I wrote this

Comment: Note that if you can use `ror`, you can implement this easily as `mov cx,bx; ror bl,4; ror bh,4`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pure 8086 assembly solution is this:

```
mov bx, 1234h ; bx = 1234h === input
mov dx, bx    ; dx = 1234h
shr bx, 8     ; bx = 0012h
shl dx, 8     ; dx = 3400h
mov ax, bx    ; ax = 0012h
mov cx, dx    ; cx = 3400h
shr bx, 4     ; bx = 0001h
shl ax, 4     ; ax = 0120h
shr cx, 4     ; cx = 0340h
shl dx, 4     ; dx = 4000h
and ax, 00F0h ; ax = 0020h
and cx, 0F00h ; cx = 0300h
or  ax, bx    ; ax = 0021h
or  cx, dx    ; cx = 4300h
or  ax, cx    ; ax = 4321h === output
```

Comment: You are using `mov` instructions. `mov` is not one of the allowed instructions. You can use `xor dest,dest; or dest,src` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't mentioned if using other registers is allowed, so I'm going to assume that it is.

I'll just show some C-code that demonstrates a way of doing what you want with the given set of instructions, and leave up to you to translate it into x86 assembly since that should be trivial:

```
CX = (BX & 1) << 12;
AX = (BX & 2) << 12;
CX |= AX;
AX = (BX & 4) << 12;
CX |= AX;
AX = (BX & 8) << 12;
CX |= AX;

AX = (BX & 0x10) << 4;
CX |= AX;
AX = (BX & 0x20) << 4;
CX |= AX;
AX = (BX & 0x40) << 4;
CX |= AX;
AX = (BX & 0x80) << 4;
CX |= AX;

AX = (BX & 0x100) >> 4;
CX |= AX;
AX = (BX & 0x200) >> 4;
CX |= AX;
AX = (BX & 0x400) >> 4;
CX |= AX;
AX = (BX & 0x800) >> 4;
CX |= AX;

AX = (BX & 0x1000) >> 12;
CX |= AX;
AX = (BX & 0x2000) >> 12;
CX |= AX;
AX = (BX & 0x4000) >> 12;
CX |= AX;
AX = (BX & 0x8000) >> 12;
CX |= AX;
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a lookup table `lut` with 65536 entries containing the map you need. Then use code like this:

```
        .data
lut:    .short 0x0000
        .short 0x1000
        ...
        .short 0xefff
        .short 0xffff

        .text
foo:
        xor %ecx,%ecx
        and $0xffff,%ebx
        or lut(,%rbx,2),%cx
```

Comment: You are only allowed to use `SHR`, `SHL`, `AND`, `OR`, `XOR`. You have a `RET` in your answer.

Comment: @JeremyP I'm terribly sorry. I have immediately removed the illegal instruction.